# Swift: nil в enum

Tags: swift, исключения, enum

У меня есть такое объявление перечисления:

```
enum TypeOfCollision: Int {
    case inelastic
    case elastic
}
```

Мне нужно ввести 0 или 1 с консоли, чтобы выбрать один из кейсов:

```
let typeOfCollision: TypeOfCollision? = TypeOfCollision(rawValue: Int(readLine()!)!)
```

Однако при вводе другого типа данных кидается fatalError() при попытке извлечь nil из Int. Так как enum определен как Int, то принудительное извлечение убрать не получится. Есть идея просто определить enum как Optional Int, но тут Xcode выдает ошибку:

> 'TypeOfCollision' declares raw type 'Int?', but does not conform to RawRepresentable and conformance could not be synthesized

В качестве решения он предлагает добавить строчку:

```
typealias RawValue = <#type#>
```

Однако я не совсем понимаю, что в этой строчке надо написать. Объясните, пожалуйста, что надо написать в этой строчке, чтобы кейсы могли содержать nil, либо подскажите, как можно по-другому обработать неверный тип данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать вариант с дефолтным значением при получении невалидных значений

```
let typeOfCollision: TypeOfCollision? = TypeOfCollision(rawValue: Int(data) ?? TypeOfCollision.inelastic.rawValue)
```